# CollectionView Issue on iPhone 7/8 plus, iPhone 7/8s & iPhone X

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

This is probably a simple issue but, I don't know how to get rid of it.

**My problem:**

- When I run on iPhone 8 Plus, my CollectionView is exactly what
  I expect (see Image1).
- When I run on iPhone X, my CollectionView
  has a different layout (see Image2).

**What I would like:**

Using a UICollectionView, I would like to get a layout like Image1, on every single iPhone.

Could you pls give me some tips to solve this issue ?

**Image1 (Expected Result):**

Result on the iPhone 8 Plus

[image]

**Image2 (Wrong Result):**

Result on the iPhone X

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use following Delegate method: `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout`

```
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,
                    layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout,
                    sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {

          return CGSize(width: (self.view.frame.width - 8) / 3.0 , height: (self.view.frame.width - 8) / 3.0)
     }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, insetForSectionAt section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets {

        return UIEdgeInsetsMake(8, 8, 0, 8)
    }
```

Comment: @veerendrapratapsingh Happy Coding :)

Comment: Thanks Its Working.

Comment: Happy Coding :) @Sonu