# CollectionView Label auto layout of multi-line label is getting trapped for small screen iOS devices

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uilabel

There are two labels within `CollectionViewCell` (`labelLeft` and `labelRight`). The following code makes sure multiline label grows without having to calculate height of label. The code works perfectly fine for larger screens (iPhone 7 Plus etc), but the code gets trapped with iPhone 5S. It constantly looks for collectionView properties with the app hanging. I have tried to reduce the width, but no success so far, maybe because I don't understand how `estimatedItemSize` works. Any help would be appreciated.

```
let dummyArrayRight: [String] = ["dummy text left left left left left left LEFT", "dummy text left LEFT"]
let dummyArrayLeft: [String] = ["dummy text RIGHT RIGHT RIGHT RIGHT", "dummy text right right right right right right right right right RIGHT"]
```

**TableViewCell:**

```
if let flowLayout = cell.collectionView.collectionViewLayout as? UICollectionViewFlowLayout {
    flowLayout.estimatedItemSize = CGSize(width: 1, height: 1)
    flowLayout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0)
    flowLayout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 0
    flowLayout.minimumLineSpacing = 0
}
```

**CollectionViewCell:**

```
cell.labelLeft.attributedText = self.dummyArrayLeft[indexPath.row].html2AttributedString
cell.labelRight.attributedText = self.dummyArrayRight[indexPath.row].html2AttributedString

let widthSize = UIScreen.main.bounds.width / 2
cell.labelLeft.preferredMaxLayoutWidth = widthSize
cell.labelRight.preferredMaxLayoutWidth = widthSize
cell.collectionLabel.textAlignment = .left
cell.labelRight.textAlignment = .right
```

[image]

Comment: If you show some screenshot, it may help us..

Answer (score 0):

Use following Delegate method: `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout`

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,
                    layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout,
                    sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {

          return CGSize(width: (self.view.frame.width - 8) / 2.0 , height: (self.view.frame.width - 8) / 2.0)
     }

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, insetForSectionAt section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets {

        return UIEdgeInsetsMake(8, 8, 0, 8)
    }
```

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49426057/6165231) is the Original Answer of it.

Comment: Thanks Abhishek, but I was avoiding `itemSize`  - I tried this before which is not good for multi-line labels, unless calculating height based on fonts etc. I want the labels to be neat with no gaps which `estimatedItemSize` handles really well. I have two labels within a tableViewCell and they both need to touch right and left screen respectively (or aligned), which I managed with `estimatedItemSize`.

Comment: Show some screenshot, what you want and what you are getting.. @Curtis

Comment: I have edited the code and added a screenshot, hope it's clearer now?

Comment: No, I afraid to say you but I didn’t understand at all.. 